# How do I disable Bitlocker Encryption settings using Intune?

Tags: bitlocker, microsoft-intune

We've activated Intune Bitlocker encryption and configured it needs a password to unlock.

Since we don't want our users to change the Bitlocker pin, we want to disable the Settings below.

[Bitlocker Encryption settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttNHR.png)

For all non Germans, it's under:

```
Control Panel\System and Security\BitLocker Drive Encryption
```

Thanks for any help!
:)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the GPO setting **Disallow standard users from changing the PIN or password**.
It can be found at `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Operating System Drives`

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-group-policy-settings#bkmk-dpinchange